# "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" and error creating bean with name "entityManagerFactory"

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Hi I am a beginner in SpringBoot and am kind of on my own as I have to do this as a project for an institution but don't have much guidance so any(and I mean any) help would be good.
I am trying to run MyStudySkillsAppApplication.java main class as to make a local database that I can later change with Project.java and Student.java as table files and with each having their own CRUD repository intializers named after them like ProjectRepository.java and StudentRepository.java. I got the errors described in the title which I could not fix at the moment so guidance on how to fix it would be helpful.

The error pasted from terminal is :

```
2021-12-20 14:12:36.370  INFO 6148 --- [           main] c.S.S.StudySkillsAppApplication          : Starting StudySkillsAppApplication using Java 11.0.11 on LAPTOP-PL24G5VM with PID 6148 (C:\Users\Abdulrahman\Desktop\formysqlsetup\4thtry\StudySkillsApp\target\classes started by Abdulrahman in C:\Users\Abdulrahman\Desktop\formysqlsetup\4thtry\StudySkillsApp)
2021-12-20 14:12:36.373  INFO 6148 --- [           main] c.S.S.StudySkillsAppApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-20 14:12:36.910  INFO 6148 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-12-20 14:12:36.942  INFO 6148 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 25 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-12-20 14:12:37.258  INFO 6148 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-12-20 14:12:37.264  INFO 6148 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-12-20 14:12:37.264  INFO 6148 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2021-12-20 14:12:37.332  INFO 6148 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-12-20 14:12:37.333  INFO 6148 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 895 ms
2021-12-20 14:12:37.424  INFO 6148 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-12-20 14:12:38.664 ERROR 6148 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
```

[image: error1]

[image: endoferror1]

this error was repeated 2 other times with same error message but different exceptions(if that helps)

[image: error2]

[image: endoferror2]

org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
... 33 common frames omitted

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the code for StudySkillsAppApplication.java:

```
package com.StudySkillsApp.StudySkillsApp;

import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@SpringBootApplication

@RestController

public class StudySkillsAppApplication {

    @Autowired
    ProjectRepository projectsRepo;

    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentsRepo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StudySkillsAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Here is ProjectRepository.java which is the crud repo:

```
package com.StudySkillsApp.StudySkillsApp;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project, Long>
{

}
```

And here is Project:
package com.StudySkillsApp.StudySkillsApp;

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity @Table(name="projects")
class Project {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name="id") @Getter @Setter
    Long id;
    
    @Column(name="name") @Getter @Setter
    String projectName;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="project") @Getter @Setter
    List<Student> teamMembers;
    
    public Project() {
        projectName = "";
    }
    
    public Project(String name) {
        projectName = name;
    }
}
```

if you would like me to upload Student.java or StudentRepository.java lmk but it was written in a similar if not identical manor to Project and ProjectRepository but just changing attributes of Student. Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: are you able to login to mysql directly with 'user' and 'password'?

Comment: your app can not connect with the user password combination, but the basics are all sound, so check if the user has all grants to allow him to connect